# How to discover the Paths to Loading Binaries

Tags: linux, windows, macos, dll, shared-libraries

I have a problem where I need to know the filesystem path of the current binary, as well as those of any loading (as opposed to loaded) binaries. Here is an example (for Windows):  Say we have an executable `A.exe`, which dynamically binds to `B.dll`, which in turn binds to `C.dll`. How could code executing in `C.dll` get the file paths of `C.dll`, `B.dll`, and `A.exe`?

Oh, and I need to be able to do it on Linux, Mac, and Windows.

- On **Linux**, the closest thing I've found is `dl_iterate_phdr`, but the who-loaded-who info is missing.
- On **Windows**, The `Dynamic-Link` functions don't have quite the right functionality.
- On **Mac**, all I can find is what's in dlfcn.h, which is rather pithy for this purpose.

Thanks.